# How to replace one dynamic array with another without causing memory leak?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, memory-leaks

This is a simple question and I'm kind of a beginner, but I would just like to confirm this.

Say I have a class object int * data, which is pointing to an array of 5 ints. Say I have a function that would replace data with 5 arguments, as illustrated below.

```
void replaceData(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e){
    int * temp = new int[5];

    temp[0] = a;
    temp[1] = b;
    temp[2] = c;
    temp[3] = d;
    temp[4] = e;

    data = temp;           
}
```

I am concerned that this would cause a memory leak, because if data already had 5 ints in there, they would still be floating around. I am tempted to change it in the following way to avoid this:

```
void replaceData(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e){
    int * temp = new int[5];

    temp[0] = a;
    temp[1] = b;
    temp[2] = c;
    temp[3] = d;
    temp[4] = e;

    delete data;     //would this prevent a memory leak? 
    data = temp;
    temp = 0;           
}
```

Thank you very much for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.

The `delete` operator is for pointers to single objects.  You need to do `delete[] data` for this to work.  Zeroing the temp pointer at the end doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If `data` was allocated in the same way as you are allocating `temp` then yes, you would need to free the old array first before modifying the pointer - otherwise you will have a memory leak.

Note that if you allocate an array (`new int[5]`) then you must free the array like this:

```
delete[] data;
```

Also, it's much better to use an STL container like `std::vector` rather than allocating arrays manually, as all the memory management is handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be correct if it were `delete[]` instead of `delete`. If the size is hardcoded though, there's no point in using a dynamically allocated array (at least not in this context). Just use an `int temp[5];`.

Better yet, just use vectors. Then it's a simple call to `std::swap`.